# Save image with caption in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to save an image to my iPhone gallery by adding some caption to it.I Now whenever i want to search that caption in my photo app it should return that images which i saved with same caption.So is it possible to save images to gallery in such way & retrieve all the images.

Thanks

Comment: usetimeStamp with caption , it shows on different in every time

Comment: No i don't want to embed text on image.If i search a caption then it must show me that image

Comment: you can put sticker on image.

Comment: please read my above comment